# Optimization of nested loop in Python while parsing binary data

Tags: python, parsing, optimization, nested-loops, binary-data

I have to parse some text which is binary, represented in hex decimals, such as ***hex_bytes*** in the code below. In this example, there are 32 variables and 3 points, which means that I have 32 variables repeated 3 times. 
***hex_bytes*** contains values for 32 variables once and after that again and also the third time.
Thing is that I need to convert for the first variable in double precision (8 bytes), and all other in single-precision (4 bytes).

I made an array (32 columns and 3 rows) and I filled only the first column with double precision converted values and all other with single-precision values.

I have a nested loop and it works, but I wonder is there some solution that is faster than the nested loop? I tried with a ***lambda()*** function, also with ***zip()***, but I cannot implement them appropriately in my code. I have a problem implementing an increment of 8 or 16.

Here is the code:

```
import binascii
from struct import *
import numpy as np

hex_bytes = b'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'

NoPoints = 3
NoVariables = 32

Values = np.zeros((NoPoints,NoVariables))
BinaryStart = 0

for NoPt in range(NoPoints):
    for NoVar in range(NoVariables):
        if NoVar == 0:
            Values[NoPt,NoVar], = unpack('d', binascii.a2b_hex(hex_bytes[BinaryStart:BinaryStart+16]))
            BinaryStart +=16
        else:
            Values[NoPt,NoVar], = unpack('f', binascii.a2b_hex(hex_bytes[BinaryStart:BinaryStart+8]))
            BinaryStart += 8
```

Note that 8 binary characters represent 4 bytes and 16 binary characters represent 8 bytes (that is the reason why 8 and 16 appear in the code).

Comment: _In this example, there are 32 variables and 3 points_ - no, there are actually 6 points, and you convert only the first half of **hex_bytes**. Is that desired, or a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it *is faster than the nested loop*, but we can do without loops by constructing an appropriate unpack format string and unpacking all at once:

```
Values = np.array(unpack('='+('d'+str(NoVariables-1)+'f')*NoPoints, binascii.a2b_hex(hex_bytes)))\
           .reshape((NoPoints, NoVariables))
```

The first character `=` of the format string is needed to prevent alignment padding between `f` and `d`.

Comment: @Armali-obviosly that I don't understand how unpack() works. Great! More than two times faster. I have one variation - how to change the code if I have for each variable two double-precision values to convert?

Comment: Values = np.array(unpack(('dd')*NoVariables*NoPoints, binascii.a2b_hex(hex_bytes)))\ .reshape((NoPoints, NoVariables, 2)...I did it with this. Thank you.

Comment: Now you obviously understood how unpack() works. ;-)